# how to Post List<PointF> with retrofit multipart on android?

Tags: android, arraylist, retrofit, multipart

i want to make an android app which can send an image and PointF from canvas. i've already success to send an image with retorifit multipart. and my next goal is to send List. but i confused how to send it?

this is code for send image

```
final ProgressRequestBody fileBody = new ProgressRequestBody(uploadFile, this);
                final MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", uploadFile.getName(), fileBody);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        Observable<String> upload = apiService.uploadFile(body);

                        upload.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onNext(String s) {

                                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

                                        Glide.with(PolygonActivity.this)
                                                .load(s)
                                                .apply(RequestOptions.skipMemoryCacheOf(true))
                                                .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                                                .into(sourceImageView);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                                        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                                        Toast.makeText(PolygonActivity.this, "error response: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete() {

                                    }
                                });

                    }}).start();
```

this is my ApiService

```
@Multipart
    @POST("api/upload")
    Observable<String> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

and i want to send private List pointFS = new ArrayList<>(); . when i toast pointFS it show [PointF(312.31,432.1212),PointF(344.34,53.131)]. so i confused how to send it over retrofit. i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like this

```
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    String pointFListString= gson.toJson(pointFSArrayList);
RequestBody pointFList= RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), pointFListString);

    @Multipart
        @POST("api/upload")
        Observable<String> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                      @Part("pointFArrayKey") RequestBody pointFList);
```